# Php switch case cannot echo out Chinese characters

Tags: php, switch-statement, html-select

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Greeting Service!</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<form method="post" action="">
<h1>What's Your Name?</h1>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name Here" />
<h4>Greet me in:
<select name="language">
<option value="option1">English</option>
<option value="option2">Chinese</option>
<option value="option3">French</option>
</select>
</h4>
<input type="submit" value="Greet Me!" />
<?php
if (isset($_POST['language'])) {
$language = $_POST['language'];
switch ($_POST['language']) {
case "option1":
$result = "Hello, {$_POST['name']}!"; 
break;
case "option2":
$result = "你好, {$_POST['name']}!"; 
break;
case "option3":
$result = "Bonjour, {$_POST['name']}!"; 
break;
}
echo $result;
}
?>
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code. I'm not sure why when i select the Chinese option to greet the name typed in the text box, it echoes out random letters with dots and fractions. I'm exactly sure why this happens, because when i select the name to echoed out in French or English it appears to be fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's not switch case issue, it's character set.

Set `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`